# Simplification of a limit

Tags: limits

I was just solving a problem in which a gp involving exponential terms was formed. I got this --> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2}{n} \left[e^{-1} \frac{({(e^{\frac{2}{n}}})^{n}-1)}{e^{\frac{2}{n}}-1}\right]$$ but I'm unable to reduce it further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i can not read this!

Comment: I'll just edit it. Give me 2 minutes.

Comment: tried getting it to compile, I hope it is what you wanted to write

Comment: Not exactly but I've made the changes and I've finally edited this up, so please lift up the downvotes.

Comment: I cant lift any downvotes, but I gave you one up instead.

Answer (score 1):

By linearity and $\left({e^{\frac 2n}}\right)^n=e^2$ we need to evaluate
$$\frac {2(e^2-1)}{e} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{\frac 2n}-1)}$$
Since
$$n\left( e^{\frac 2n} - 1\right)=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{\frac 4n}-1}{e^\frac 2n+1}}{\dfrac 1n}$$
so by de l'Hospital's rule
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {n(e^{\frac 2n}-1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{-2e^\frac 6n-4e^\frac 4n-2e^\frac 2n}{n^2\left(e^{\frac 2n}+1\right)^2}}{-\dfrac{1}{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2e^\frac 2n = 2$$

Plugging this in we finally see that the result is $\boxed{e-\frac 1e=2\sinh 1}$